# bash script - iterate recursively on 2 directories

Tags: bash, recursion, copy

I need a way to recursively iterate through a directory and copy contents over to another directory following the same directory structure.
For instance, I have the below:

```
src1/
    dir1/
      sub-dir1.1/
      file1.1
    dir2/
      sub-dir2.1/
    file1
```

Now, I have another directory elsewhere, which has a similar structure as the above but with less/more files + directories.

```
src2/
    dir1/
      sub-dir1.1/
      file1.1
      file1.2
    dir2/
    dir3/
    file4
```

I need to copy all contents over from src1 to src2 including all sub-directories under dir1 and dir2. Is there a way to do rather than drilling down to each file under N subdirectories and copying files? 
I tried using a "cp -r" but it gives me a "cp: will not overwrite just-created"
Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsync` command is well suited to this.

Something like this might achieve what you want:

```
rsync -av src1/ src2/
```

Try using the `-n` flag to begin with to run it in "dry-run" or test mode. This shows you what files it will copy without actually making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `rsync -a`ing the two folders